# What will the scope of a variable inside a Spring session scoped bean?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using Spring,JSF,Richfaces in my project and i am initialized all JSF beans in `application-context.xml` file something like this

```
<bean id="inventoriesBean" class="com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.sure.InventoriesBean"
              parent="baseWorkOrderBean" scope="session">
        <property name="templateBean" ref="templateBean" />
        <property name="inventoriesWorkOrder" ref="inventoriesWorkOrder" />
        <property name="loginBean" ref="loginBean" />
        <property name="equipmentVO" ref="equipmentVO" />
        <property name="selectedEquipment" ref="selectedEquipment" />
        <property name="inventoryFilter" ref="InventoryFilter" />
    </bean>
```

Now my question is that Let us suppose i have a list **invertoryList** in **InventoriesBean.java** and with a **refresh** button i am  initializing(Doing empty) this list again

```
public void refreshSure() {
invertoryList = new ArrayList();
}
```

Will `invertoryList` will be empty ? While **InventoriesBean.java** already in session scope . When i am calling refresh method through **JSF** page it is showing old data its all because the bean have `session` scope? or something else?

```
 <a4j:commandButton value="ServiceButton"  action="#{inventoriesBean.refreshSure()}" render="treeCust"></a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: The bean isn't session scoped, you need `<aop:scoped-proxy />` added to the bean definition for that.

Comment: scope="session" is already there why this bean is not in session?

Comment: Because when injecting it into different scoped beans you need a scoped proxy without it the scope isn't doing much. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection.

Comment: Ok got ut point ...So why i have to logout to check the new data? It loading same data again and again even after refreshing to clicking on some button also refreshing List its not updating it when i am doing tab changes then its removing List record and idea what can be issue?